# Solr edismax Query Parser Operators

Tags: solr, edismax, query-parser

I have two queries about edismax parser --->

1.Does edismax parser support && || for AND and OR operators ? 
2.Also Does is support 'not' for NOT operator like and/or for AND/OR ?

If edismax parser don't support this, how can I extend this parser and add this functionality ?

Thanks in advance. Devendra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the JIRA [SOLR-1553](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1553) for the Edismax Parser.
It does support the boolean operators check [Documentation](http://docs.lucidworks.com/display/solr/The+Extended+DisMax+Query+Parser)

```
supports queries such as AND, OR, NOT, -, and +.
treats "and" and "or" as "AND" and "OR" in Lucene syntax mode.
```

Also for `AND` the operator is `+`, `NOT` with a `-` and `OR` does not need an operator.

Comment: So how can we overcome this problem of supporting other operators ? I want to implement || and && operators.

Comment: you can handle it on the client side or customer handler before the query reaches solr.

Comment: Solr 4.0 and higher version supports || and && operators. Upgraded to 4.0 QueryParser.